# My javascript on another site, what domain is it checking cookies for?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am having some cookie issues and am trying to troubleshoot.

So...

I have a script that I put on other website domains

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://siteA.com/script.php"></script>
```

Lets say I put this script on siteB

in http://siteA.com/script.php I have it check for a cookie with this code

```
    function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var id = getCookie("mycookiename");
    if (id == "1234") {
        redirect()
    } else {

        something()

    }
}
```

So my question is, is this javascript checking for the cookie on siteA or siteB?

Comment: The PHP (server) at siteA will receive cookies for siteA. JavaScript will access the cookies of the page it runs in, which is siteB in your example

Answer (score 1):

(Client-side) JavaScript code (on a webpage) *always* executes in the context of the *document* it is loaded into, so it will have access to the cookies belonging to the document.

You could generate the JavaScript using server side code (written in any language you like) and that server side code would have access to the cookies for the URI hosting the JS (and could inject the data into the JavaScript file). (This is usually not a good idea).

Comment: Why "usually not a good idea"? IIRC that's the way authentication works for JSONP :-)

Comment: @Bergi — Because *usually* you want scripts to be easily cacheable static resources. JSONP is a hack to use JS as a data serialisation format in browsers that don't support CORS.

Answer (score 0):

It will check on siteB's cookie (the page that is running the code). If it wouldn't it would lead to security issues. Also CDN libraries wouldn't work as they would check the cookie on the CDN's domain, not on the domain you really want to check.